# Nested foreach loop to LINQ conversion

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert these nested foreach loop to LINQ but output is coming in form of `IEnumerable<BPAddress>`. Is there any solution?

```
foreach (var cmt in BPAddresss)
{
   foreach (var t in cmt.BPPhones)
   {
       if (t.PHON_NUMB.Length> 11)
       {
           
       }
   }
}
```

LINQ Code

```
var k37 = Target.BPAddresss.Where(x => x.BPPhones.Where(y => y.PHON_NUMB.Length > 11).Count() > 0);
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't do anything, what are you trying to actually achieve? And why do you think Linq would be better?

Comment: Solution for what exactly? It will return you an IEnumerable<T>. It seems like you don't want it to return anything but update the existing BPAddresss.

Comment: You can try to use include in line: Target.BPAddresss.Include("BPPhones")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any`:

```
var query = Target.BPAddresss
    .Where(x => x.BPPhones.Any(y => y.PHON_NUMB.Length > 11));
```

But note that this will not filter the children by this condition. It just checks if there is at least one phone-number longer than 11 characters.

If you need to filter them, you could use `SelectMany`:

```
var longPhoneNumbers = Target.BPAddresss
    .SelectMany(x => x.BPPhones.Where(y => y.PHON_NUMB.Length > 11));
```

Comment: Both of them are producing the same result just a difference of selectmany directly targeting BPPhones while iterating through the loop.

Comment: @AdilAsif: No,  the result type is different. The first filters addresses, the second filters phone-numbers. If you have more than one phone-number per address, you will notice that the addresses still contain numbers with length <= 1.

Comment: That's right, but the result I want from Linq is of boolean type but in this case, it is IEnumerable which is not my requirement I have to iterate again BPAdresss, the solution which I found is this:  var J = BPAddress.SelectMany(x => x.BPPhones.ToList()).Where(y => y.BPPhones_Numb.Length > 11).Count() > 1;

Comment: @AdilAsif: you have  said nothing about your requirements in your question, so i was fixing your Compiler error and tried to guess what you need. Your original nested for each was not initializing a bool and exited the loops but continueing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance it really helped me to understand the concept, and solve the problem. Thanks for your time.